# Add a word between the string after word

Tags: c#

I want to add a word between the string after word "Photo/" like :

```
string path ="C:/Users/tsgill/Desktop/myApp/Photo/11686_Snap1.png"
```

insert word "thumb/" like :

```
string path ="C:/Users/tsgill/Desktop/myApp/Photo/thumb/11686_Snap1.png"
```

i have try to split this but concat the all things not correctly. let me know how can i do this easily,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [`Path` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string path = "C:/Users/tsgill/Desktop/myApp/Photo/11686_Snap1.png";
path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path), "thumb", Path.GetFileName(path));
```

Answer (score 3):

IF you know exactly where you need to put this, you can do a replace:

```
string path = path.Replace("Photo", "Photo/thumb");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you meant you want to add after the last "/"

```
        string path = "C:/Users/tsgill/Desktop/myApp/Photo/11686_Snap1.png";
        path=path.Insert(path.LastIndexOf('/')+1, "Thumb/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method to do it dynamically:

```
public string modify(string yourPath,string yourInsertedWord, string yourWordToChange)
{ 
    int index = yourPath.LastIndexOf(yourWordToChange) 
    string stringresult = yourPath.insert(index,yourInsertedWord);
    return stringresult;
}
```

Comment: How is this different from the other answers? The answer by @Tyress is almost identical and probably more likely to work because it uses `LastIndexOf`

Comment: Yes i didnt see his answer, while i was typing. May it is usefull to have all this inside a method. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all other answers (Tim Schmelter ones seems to be the cleanest IMHO, but it depends of your need), I just want to add that if you need more control on each folders which compose your directory, you can split and manage them using :

```
string[] directories = mypath.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
```

Then rebuild it, adding the missing subdirectory part at the right place.

Note : as stated this is not intended to be a full answer, but a complement to others ones.

Comment: This will create a lot of temporary strings. It's far cheaper to use a regex and do a Replace. No temporary strings are created, only the final string

Comment: Agree about the temporary strings, but let me doubt of that :  Regexes are not really known to be "cheap" things...

Comment: That's a very unfortunate misconception. Difficult to understand maybe, but a lot faster than splitting strings by hand, even before you count the gains by reduced garbage collections. A regex *compiles* its pattern, a static regex means you don't need to compile every time and is thread safe so it can be reused. The matching result is a tree of indexes in the original string so no temporary strings are created. Performance is actually orders of magnitude better for simple patterns, even better for more complex ones